# How can I set the value of textbox to 0 if blank or empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following snippet in my js file:

```
if ($("#LengthenCheckBox").is(":checked")) {
                $("#Length").data(kendoTextBox).enable(true);

                //If Lengthening field is blank, default to zero
                if ($("#Length").data(kendoTextBox) == "") {
                    $("#Length").data(kendoTextBox).value("0");
                };

                document.getElementById("Lengthen").value = true;
else {

            if ($("#Length").data(kendoTextBox) == "") {
                $("#Length").data(kendoTextBox).value("0");
            }
            else {
                $("#Length").data(kendoTextBox).value();
            }
            $("#Length").data(kendoTextBox).enable(false);
```

However, I just want the value of the textbox to equal 0 if no value is entered or the textbox is blank. How can I adjust the following above?

EDIT:

How can I set the value of textbox to 0 if blank or empty?

That is I have a simple textbox, if the user enters no value inside the textbox or the user leaves the textbox blank and goes somewhere else, I want it to automatically default back to 0 and not blank! I never want the textbox to be blank but contain some value whether it's 0 or any other integer value but never blank.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Re-running a jQuery selector (even a fast ID one) is a bad idea. Use a local var to store it e.g. `var $length = $("#Length");`

Comment: @God is good: Don't lengthen a jQuery example with raw JS :) Did you pull `textbox` out of thin air as that is not in the original?

Comment: Yes I did, @TrueBlueAussie.

Comment: First off, why are you checking the data attribute kendoTextBox's value when you say you want to check the field's value? Second, in jQuery it's `.val("0")`, not `.value("0")`.

Comment: `if $('#textbox').val() === ''){$('#textbox').val('0');}`

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I'm not super comfortable with jQuery yet.  Is my above comment correct?

Comment: would be nice to see the corresponding html.

Comment: i just updated my answer cause i thought he really wants to check the length of his data-attribute "kendoTextBox". still not sure what he really wants to check.

Comment: Please see edit! Sorry for the confusion everyone.

Comment: i can still not see any html.

Comment: What do you consider "blank"? If I enter a bunch of spaces, is that considered blank?

Comment: @nullability, yes that should be considered blank and also if there are no spaces too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**update 3:** if you consider spaces inside the textbox as "blank" as well:

```
$("#Length").on("blur", function () {
    if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
        $(this).val("0");
    }
});
//trigger blur once for the initial setup:
$("#Length").trigger("blur");
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/northkildonan/n1dd2opx/3/

**update 2:** if you want the textbox to be `0` when it's left blank at all times:

```
$("#Length").on("blur", function () {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
        $(this).val("0");
    }
});
//trigger blur once for the initial setup:
$("#Length").trigger("blur");
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/northkildonan/n1dd2opx/1/

**update:** if you want to check for the length of a textbox with the id "Length", then it's:

```
if ($("#Length").val().length == 0) {
    $("#Length").val("0");
};
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/northkildonan/n1dd2opx/

Comment: I'm so sorry, I don't want to check the length of a textbox. I just want to set the textbox default value to 0 if no the textbox value is blank.

Comment: @Euridice01 yes, but that's exactly what my code does.

Comment: Why is the way I did it above wrong? Why are you checking the length of the textbox?

Comment: @Euridice01 I don't check the length of the textbox, I check the length of the **value** of the text box. and if your textbox is **blank** the length of its value is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just five small lines of code:

```
$("#buttonid").on('click', function() {
   if ($("#textboxid").val() == "") {
      $("#textboxid").val("0");
   }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#amount").on("blur", function () {
if ($(this).val().trim().length == 0) {
    $(this).val("0");
}});});
```

Comment: Please explain what you did editing your answer, avoid only code answer and take a look to : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer